# Get merged cell value in every JSON object

Tags: js-xlsx

I have an excel file that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, there are some merged cells. I've been using js-xlsx to convert the data to JSON objects in my application. Here is the code:

```
onFileLoad(loadedEvent: any) {
    let data = new Uint8Array(loadedEvent.target.result);
    let arr: Array<string> = new Array();
    for (let i = 0; i != data.length; i++) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
    let bstr = arr.join("");
    let wb: XLSX.IWorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });
    let workSheet = wb.Sheets[wb.SheetNames[0]];
    let jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workSheet, {raw: true });
    console.log(jsonData);
}
```

The code works fine for the row where it says "40", but at "41" the JSON object does not contain the fields from the merged cells. You can see that here:

[image]

Is there any way to make the  values from the merged cells be in every JSON object?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to handle these separately, the reader will just pick up the upper left cell from merged ranges.  If you want to apply some sort of handling after reading the object you can access the merged cells within workbook.Sheets[data_sheet_name]["!merges"] as

```
[
{//start of merge
s:{c:col_num, r:row_num},
//end of merge
e: {c:col_num, r:row_num}
},
more merge objects...
 ]
```

Can use that to find your data and copy it across if you like.